# We have both [zero-inflated] and [zero-inflation] tags. Do we need both?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

If the usage is distinct, [this question's usage](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244425/how-to-handle-0-inflated-data-set) suggests the distinction is opaque. But to my understanding, the only difference is morphological inflection and not statistical.

Comment: I have just made them synonyms.  [tag:zero-inflation] was far more popular than [tag:zero-inflated], so I made the former the target (that is, the default value).

Comment: Wow, fast turnaround, @whuber. Could you take a look at our [Current tag synonym candidates](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1200/7290) thread & see if there is anything actionable there? We still have `[unbalanced]` & `[imbalanced]`, eg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whuber's comment addresses this: the two are now synonyms.